# Cannot connect to mySQL DB from jsp in Eclipse

Tags: java, html, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I am trying to connect to a DB from jsp in eclipse , in order to build a webite. I know the connection works fine from a .java file. I have the mysql connector added and everything, but I can't figure out why it won't connect. Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>

<%


    Connection con=null;

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/e-health?useSSL=false","root","root");
        System.out.println("Connection successful");
        out.println("Connection successful");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Connection failed");
    }

    out.println("Loged in, connected to the DB");
%>
<a href = "welcome.html">Welcome</a><br>
<a href= "index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?
you possibly are missing port number of which it should connect after localhost

Comment: @user1063108 Connection failed
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver . This is the error. But I have the mysql connector in referenced libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Import the packages at the top of the program

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Connection"%>
```

Comment: I have tried that, too. The problem was that I had to have both the .html and the .jsp files in the same folder